# photoswipe on android smartphone looses caption

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I have made a series of testcases using photoswipe for my website
    http://www.bomengids.nl/2015/soorten2015.html

One of the testcases show just 4 pics:
   http://www.bomengids.nl/2015/photoswipe-css/zip/index7.html

Both the clicking with mouse on a desktop and tapping on a smartphone screen (android + chrome) plus on a tablet (ipad ios8.4 chrome+) works fine.

However, on android the caption does not appear. What to do? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: by the way all testcases plus descriptions are here http://www.bomengids.nl/2015/photoswipe-css/zip/photoswipe-testcases.html

Comment: can nobody help? This is crucial for my website to work on smartphones. Captions work on all screens but on the smallest. http://www.bomengids.nl/2015/soorten/Anna_Paulownaboom__Paulownia_tomentosa__Empress_tree__Blauglockenbaum--Paulownie__Paulownia_tomentosa.html